# Conflict with loading up mock data for unit testing between PyCharm and unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I have a Python project structure as follows.

```
.
├── data
├── src
│   ├── module1
│   └── module2
└── tests
    ├── base
    ├── module1
    └── module2
```

The `data` directory is where I put mock data for use in unit test (e.g. CSV files). If I am inside PyCharm, inside a unit test, I can use a relative path as below and use the IDE to run a unit test (using `unittests`) successfully.

```
pd.read_csv('../../data/mock.csv')
```

However, outside of PyCharm, I can try to run the following command to run the unit test.

```
python -m unittest tests/module1/*.py
```

I will get an error that says the file does not exists. If I change the path as follows, then running the unit test from outside PyCharm works, but running the test within PyCharm fails.

```
pd.read_csv('./data/mock.csv')
```

When I inspect the unit test configuration, I notice that the `working directory` is set to `/Users/myusername/myproject/tests/module1`. If I change the working directory to `/Users/myusername/myproject`, I get the following error: `AssertionError: Path must be within the project`.

I even tried to move the `data` directory into `tests > module1`, but the same conflict remains; now `pd.read_csv('./data/mock.csv')` works for PyCharm but fails for the terminal.

Any ideas on how to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by abstracting out getting the path to mock data.

```
def normalize_path(resource, proj_root='root_folder'):
    path = os.getcwd() # current working directory
    tokens = path.split('/') # tokens of directory path
    index = tokens.index(proj_root) # look for where project root ends
    tokens = tokens[1:index + 1] # reconstruct the path up to the project root
    p = '/'.join(tokens)
    p = f'/{p}/{resource}' # append the resource to the project root

    return p
```

In my code, now I do something like the following.

```
pd.read_csv(normalize_path('data/mock.csv'))
```

I can execute tests from the terminal or PyCharm without any problem.